# How to convert Human readable timestamp to Unix timestamp by using PowerShell?

Tags: unix, powershell, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I have a following **csv** file format, which contains some tool information and **normal** time.

> "Tool","TimeRaised" "Abod","27-Jun-14 8:32:45 AM" "Test","27-Jun-14
>   8:30:42 AM" "Groupd","27-Jun-14 8:22:01 AM" "Tize","27-Jun-14 8:15:50
>   AM" "COrd","27-Jun-14 8:00:52 AM"

I want to convert that **normal** time to **Unix** timestamp format by using PowerShell cmdlet. But I dont know which powershell cmdlet to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
PS > Get-Date -date "27-Jun-14 8:00:52 AM" -UFormat %s
1403856052
```