# Convert Date to UnixTimestamp in a "Select-Object" loop. PowerShell

Tags: powershell

My goal is to make a PS script that creates a CSV file with specefied domain users given name and a timestamp when that user was last modified in **unix timestamp format**.

I have figured out everything except how to convert the "Modified" AD Attribute value to unix timestamp and how to use that inline in the `Select-Object` "loop"

I have the following:

```
get-aduser -filter {name -like test} -property GivenName, Modified | Select-Object GivenName, Modified | Export-CSV -path C:\PS\user.csv
```

That gives me the following output

```
Test,2016-02-09 11:48:48
```

How do i go about doing something like this?:

```
...| Select-Object GivenName, Modified.convertedToUnixTimestamp() |...
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert Human readable timestamp to Unix timestamp by using PowerShell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24467492/how-to-convert-human-readable-timestamp-to-unix-timestamp-by-using-powershell)

Comment: I saw something similar to that "Possible duplicate", but how do i use it inline in my oneliner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it out myself:

```
get-aduser -filter {name -like "Test*"} -property GivenName, Modified | Select-Object GivenName, @{name="Modified_unix";Expression={Get-Date -date $_.modified -UFormat %s}} | Export-CSV -path C:\PS\user.csv
```

Comment: FYI This is called a calculated property.

Answer (score 0):

Using the link in the comments, try something like this to change the property in the pipe:

```
... | Select-Object GivenName,@{n="unixtimestamp";e={$_.Modified -UFormat ℅s}} |...
```